# C++ Design an object to take variable values and rules to apply to them

Tags: c++, software-design

This is a design question, I am not looking for implementation.

How would I "properly" design an object that takes multiple parameters of various types and (separately from a configuration) rules that test those parameters, such that the output is whether or not the values in the parameters pass the tests associated with them?

By "properly" I mean, it should be as efficient as possible, easy to add new rules to configuration at a whim and simply pass in more parameters without compilation.  Furthermore, it should not (I hope) require the the rule configuration know the index of the the parameters being passed in (as my current implementation does) and produce nicely engineered code.

Thanks.

A basic example of the interface would be as such:

Configuration:

```
num_rules: 2
rule0:
    parameter_index: 0
    comparison_operator: gt
    value: 12.3
rule1:
    parameter_index: 1
    comparison_operator: eq
    value: 19
```

recommendation object:

```
class RecoObj {
public:
    RecoObj(char *configFilename);
    bool recommend(float testParameter[]); // Returns true if all tests pass
...
}
```

This is my current configuration, which has several issues.  It requires that all the parameters are floats and it requires that the rules are aware of the index in the testParameter array against which to be compared (which means the config writer must be aware of how the programmer has loaded that array).  It feels as if there is a better design solution to this problem.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Can you please make an example of the interface you would like?

Comment: @Jefffrey - Sorry for the ambiguity.  I have added an example interface which outlines what I am currently doing (roughly).  I am really looking for a solution that solves this in a different manner all together (or perhaps this is already close?).

Answer (score 1):

I have been very successful in utilizing software testing tools (such as [Boost Unit Test Framework](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html)) for asserting constraints in my actual business. On a day-to-day basis I actually use Python's unit test framework, but the idea is exactly the same.

Suppose that a given spacecraft trajectory should never pass closer than, say, 1,000 km of a given set of bodies. You can create a "unit test" for a trajectory by using the tool as follows (pseudo code):

```
trajectory = Trajectory::ReadFromFile("mytraj")
for body in bodies:
 for state in trajectory.every_x_seconds:
  BOOST_REQUIRE_GT(state.altitude_relative_to_body(body))
```

Again: you are not testing software, but you can use the software testing tools to test your own business constraints.

Comment: I'm not even sure, the OP's nearly gets a clue if this answers is what he thinks having been asked for ...

Comment: I understand where you are going with this, and I already do use testing frameworks (I practice TDD) but I am not sure this solves my problem.  I hope by adding more info in the question I have cleared up the ambiguity.